# How to identify and redirect correct callback in managed pack containing connected app

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, customsetting, connected-apps

Our applications has different domain subdomain for each.

Lets say our domain is *.example.com

We have 
client1.example.com
client2.example.com

so on so forth

We want to package connected app.  How to identify  and redirect correct callback in managed pack containing connected app.

How do we redirect to different callback each time? depending on  client.
We dont think adding callback parameter each time makes sense, because we will have to keep adding list of clients url as and when new clients come in .

Answer (score 0):

You can create a standard callback url e.g. https://oauth.example.com/callback then use **state** variable as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm) and redirect further accordingly after you get response back from SF in Callback Page .
Something like this:
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG9lKcPoNINVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82HnFVVX19KY1uA5mu0QqEWhqKpoW3svG3XHrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCscA9GE&*redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth.example.com%2Fcallback*&**state=https%3A%2F%2Fclient1.example.com**